# What's the semantic when a field with Copy trait of a struct without Copy trait drops into a scope?

Tags: rust, ownership

The minimal example is this([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/))

```rust
struct Node {
    id: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let mut node = Node {id: 0};
    {
        node.id += 1; // seems that 'node' doesn't move and 'node.id' doesn't copy?
    }
    println!{"{:?}", node.id}; // 'node.id' has been changed?
}
```

I thought that the `node` would move to the scope and then I can't access the `node` in the last line, because what I know is that the ownership of fields belongs to the struct so when `node.id` drop into the scope, the whole node also drops into the scope and move occurs. The other outcome I can understand is that the `node.id` is still 0 because it has Copy semantic and what changed in the scope is just a copy of `node.id` but not `node.id` itself.

However, these two cases don't happen. The `node` can be accessed and `node.id` has been changed in the scope. It seems that `node` doesn't move and `node.id` doesn't copy, while the behavior is like passing a mutable reference of `node` to the scope and giving back when the scope is over.

what's the real reason for this outcome?

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign a variable in Rust, this is known as a "move":

```rust
let a = String::from("hello");
let b = a;  // a is no longer valid
```

This is similar to the concept of uninitialized memory. In fact, this is largely how the compiler reasons about things:

```rust
let a;
// compiler knows that `a` is "dead" (i.e. uninitialized)

a = String::from("hello");
// `a` is now "live"

let b = a;
// `a` is dead again
```

The exception to this is types that are `Copy`. If a type is `Copy`, moves are not destructive (i.e. the location moved from is still valid after the move):

```rust
let a;
// `a` is dead

a = 1;
// `a` is live

let b = a;
// `a` is still live, because i32: Copy
```

The same logic applies to struct fields. In general, the expression `node.id` might move `id` out of `node` (it depends on what comes after, and auto-deref rules). However, since `usize` is `Copy`, in your example the move doesn't invalidate the old location, so it's allowed.

There's a second thing happening here though, the compiler is able to distinguish between "the whole struct" and "a single field of the struct". Crucially, `node.id += 1` only attempts to move `id`, rather than moving the whole `node`, then operating on `id`.

Even if you made your block into a `move` closure, it would still compile (the `move` keyword forces a closure to take ownership of any variables it references). However, if you explicitly move `node` into the closure, **then** increment `id`, it will fail:

```rust
fn main() {
  let node = ...;
  let f = move || {
    let n = node;
    n.id += 1;
  }
  println!("{}", node.id);  // error, value borrowed after move
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation of how things work with a closure, but there is no closure in the question. The answer is way simpler than you make it here.

Comment: He was showing you how disjoint borrows work for structs inside and outside of closures since this was a recent addition to the language

Comment: Ideally, if there was such a thing as a "move block" `move { ... }` that would be easier, so between `move` closures and `async move` blocks, `move` closures felt like the more comparable example

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really quite simple: an empty block creates a sub-scope, but mutating a variable in a parent scope from a child scope does not imply a move (except in the case of a `move` closure, and there's no closure here).

Any variables you create inside of the empty block are only accessible from within that block, but you can use any outer variable from within the block and it does not cause a move unless you *actually* move it (e.g. something like `let node2 = node;` or pass-by-value to a function) but whether or not you move it is completely irrelevant to the existence of a sub-scope.

To put it bluntly, there is no "dropping a value into a scope" unless you *explicitly* move it into that scope with e.g. `let`.

For all intents and purposes, the code you've written is equivalent to:

```
let mut node = Node {id: 0};
node.id += 1;
println!{"{:?}", node.id};
```